# LocalStorage cannot set properly

Tags: javascript, local-storage, javascript-objects

I am trying to update points when the user is at location 1 and 2 and set them in my local storage. I have created a function object to store the points. when I console.log(userStats) at my location 1, the points are properly updated. However, when I  console.log(userStats) at location 2 after getting userStats to check, it goes back to zero when it should be 15. Here is my code...

```
$('.submit1').click(function(){
    if(document.getElementById("username").checkValidity() && document.getElementById("username").value !=""){
   


    //Get form values
    let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    let apoints = 0;
    let aitemsCollected = 0;
    
    
    console.log(username)
    
    

    
      let newUser = new User (username, apoints, aitemsCollected);
      console.log(newUser);
      //create our student and store to localstorage
      
      localStorage.setItem("userStats", JSON.stringify(newUser));

      showUserStats();
    }
    });
  

    function showUserStats() {
        
        if (localStorage.getItem("userStats") !== null) {
          userStats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userStats"));

              console.log(userStats);
          }
          
        };
        
    function User(username,apoints,aitemsCollected) {
      this.id = Date.now();
      this.name = username;
      this.points = apoints;
      this.itemsCollected = aitemsCollected;
         
    };


//checking whether passcode is correct 
    var location = 1; //check which location user is at
    $(".passcodesubmit").click(function(){
      var checkPasscode = ""+document.getElementById("passcode").value;
      console.log(checkPasscode);
      console.log(location);
       
    
      let userStats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userStats"));
     
      if (location == 1 && checkPasscode!="" && checkPasscode!= null && checkPasscode == "14Jk091H"){
        if (localStorage.getItem("userStats") !== null) {

          let userStats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userStats"));
          let accumulatedPoints = userStats.points + 15;
          userStats.points = accumulatedPoints ;

          let addItem = userStats.itemsCollected+1 ;
          userStats.itemsCollected = addItem;

          localStorage.setItem("userStats.points", JSON.stringify(accumulatedPoints));
          localStorage.setItem("userStats.itemsCollected", JSON.stringify(addItem));
          console.log(userStats.points);

          ++location;
         
          console.log(userStats);
          $(".bg").css("display","block");
          $(".cross1").css("display","block");
          
        }
      } else if(location == 2 && checkPasscode!="" && checkPasscode!= null && checkPasscode == "e4HP087p"){
        if (localStorage.getItem("userStats") !== null) {

          let userStats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userStats"));
          console.log(userStats);
          console.log(userStats.points);
          let accumulatedPoints = userStats.points + 15;
          userStats.points = accumulatedPoints ;
          localStorage.setItem("userStats.points", JSON.stringify(accumulatedPoints));

          let addItem = userStats.itemsCollected + 1 ;
          userStats.itemsCollected = addItem;
          localStorage.setItem("userStats.itemsCollected", JSON.stringify(addItem));
           
          console.log(userStats.points);

          ++location;
          console.log(userStats);
          collectItem3();
        } 
});
```

Comment: `"userStats"`, `"userStats.points"` and `"userStats.itemsCollected"` are 3 separate keys to unrelated items.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To have the highest likelihood of good answers, are you able to reduce this code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on minimal)?

Answer (score 0):

If the function is triggered by a user clicking a form submit button, this causes a default activity of re-loading the page (and so a new variable `location` will be initialised at the globally-scoped `var location = 1;`)

(unless you have not shown existing code where `location` is written to and retrieved from localStorage).

**I would write `location` to localStorage each time its value changes and retrieve it from localStorage before each conditional referencing it.** Otherwise, the global scope will be read for its value.

Alternatively, if using a form, open it like this: `<form onsubmit="return false">`.

If you have a button like this: `<input type="submit">` change it to a regular button:  `<button type='button'>submit</button>`

also, you could use an override in your event listener like this: `event.preventDefault()`  (`event` being whatever placeholder you use for the event listener call-back function argument).